# Java Webstart Options

Tags: java, macos, osx-leopard, jnlp, java-web-start

I am using javaws to run an application in OS X 10.5.7, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_13-b03-211), and it seems that the command line arugments are broken in os X.  I run the following command in linux and it works fine.

```
javaws -wait   -J"-Djavaws.package.runtype=debug" http://company.com/launch.jnlp
```

and the runtime gives me the property

```
javaws.package.runtype=debug.
```

But when I run the same arugment in os X, I get

```
 jnlpx.vmargs = -Djavaws.package.runtype=debug
```

Is this an error, or just an unknown feature?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
javaws -help
```

to find out the usage of jawaws.

As always, you can add "-verbose" to display additional output to debug your errors.